How to handle Qt + MySQL in a multithreaded environment?
Environment:

Qt Version: 6.3.2

MySQL Version: 9.0


I've successfully installed the MySQL driver, and my application connects to the database without issues in a single-threaded context.
Application Structure:
In my application:

The main thread reads data from the MySQL database and updates the UI.

A child thread reads data from a device and stores it in the MySQL database.


Here is how I'm adding the database in the code:
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "q");
While this compiles without issues, I get runtime errors when attempting to execute queries:
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open Query failed: QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
Alternatively, if I use this simpler declaration:
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
there are no runtime exceptions, but I encounter errors related to thread ownership:
QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: requested database does not belong to the calling thread.
Questions:

What are the differences between these two QSqlDatabase declaration methods?

How can I correctly manage MySQL database connections across threads in Qt?



    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        threadA= new Cdatathread(this);
        connect(threadA,&Cdatathread::started, this, &MainWindow::do_threadA_started);
        connect(threadA,&Cdatathread::finished,this, &MainWindow::do_threadA_finished);
        connect(threadA,&Cdatathread::newValue,this, &MainWindow::do_threadA_update);
        QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
        db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        db.setPort(3306);
        db.setDatabaseName("rice");
        db.setUserName("root");
        db.setPassword("root123");
        bool ok = db.open();
        if (ok){
            QMessageBox::information(this, "infor", "success");
        }
        else {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "infor", "open failed");
        }
    }

：


    void MainWindow::do_threadA_update()
    {
        QSqlQuery query;
        if (query.exec("SELECT hexvalue FROM value WHERE address='D100' ORDER BY timestamp_column DESC LIMIT 1")) {
            if (query.next()) {
                latestValueOfA  = query.value(0).toString();
                qDebug() ：
void Cdatathread::run() {
  m_stop = false;
  m_paused = true;
  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
  db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
  db.setPort(3306);
  db.setDatabaseName("rice");
  db.setUserName("root");
  db.setPassword("root123");
  db.open();
  while (!m_stop) //循环主体
  {
    if (!m_paused) {
      qDebug() << "testing";
      QSqlQuery query;
      query.exec("SELECT * FROM setting");
      while (query.next()) {
        QString ip = query.value(1).toString();
        int port = query.value(2).toInt();
        QString address = query.value(3).toString();
        QTcpSocket socket;
        socket.connectToHost(ip, port);
        if (socket.waitForConnected()) {
          QByteArray data = sendtxt(query.value(3).toString(), query.value(4).toString());
          socket.write(data);
          if (socket.waitForReadyRead()) {
            QByteArray rec_data = socket.readAll();
            QString hexData = rec_data.toHex().toUpper();
            qDebug() << hexData;
            QSqlQuery query;
            query.prepare("INSERT INTO value (ip, address, hexValue, datetime) VALUES (:ip, :address, :hexValue)");
            query.bindValue(":ip", ip);
            query.bindValue(":address", port);
            query.bindValue(":hexValue", hexData);
            if (!query.exec()) {
              qDebug() << "Error inserting data into value table";
            } else {
              qDebug() << "Data inserted successfully into value table";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  emit newValue();
}
msleep(500);
}
quit();
}

：

A MRE for this question is probably around 20-25 lines max. Please provide one.

You cannot use QSqlDatabase from different threads https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module

If two described parts does not communicate with each other directly, you can write two application or one application and one service (daemon)

How can I correctly manage MySQL database connections across threads in Qt? - create the QSqlDatabase instance in the thread where you want to use the connection.

Alternatively, let the secondary thread manage device reading, and use signals connected to the main thread to update the database.

I used QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL"); in both the run() function of the main thread and the child thread. However, the actual performance is not satisfactory. I read comments from others saying that QSqlDatabase cannot be shared between threads and needs to be declared in each thread. Should I move QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL"); from the run() function to its constructor?


How can I correctly manage MySQL database connections across threads in Qt?

According to Qt themselves

A database connection must only be used from within the thread that created it. Moving a connection into another thread can be done with QSqlDatabase::moveToThread().
In addition, the third party libraries used by the QSqlDrivers can impose further restrictions on using the SQL Module in a multithreaded program. Consult the manual of your database client for more information

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module

What are the differences between these two QSqlDatabase declaration methods?

One of the 2 accepts connectionName as an argument

Adds a database to the list of database connections using the driver type and the connection name connectionName. If there already exists a database connection called connectionName, that connection is removed.
The database connection is referred to by connectionName. The newly added database connection is returned.
If type is not available or could not be loaded, isValid() returns false.
If connectionName is not specified, the new connection becomes the default connection for the application, and subsequent calls to database() without the connection name argument will return the default connection. If a connectionName is provided here, use database(connectionName) to retrieve the connection.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase
EDIT:-

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "q");


While this compiles without issues, I get runtime errors when attempting to execute queries:


QSqlQuery::exec: database not open Query failed: QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")

Based on my understanding of https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/sql/sqlbrowser/browser.cpp?h=6.8#n122
You need to tweak your code to
QSqlQuery query(db);

Another way to write it would be
QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("q"));

